# Python: How to execute a JavaScript Function (with lxml)?

Tags: javascript, python, lxml

I'd like to parse a website where I need to make a JavaScript call before parsing the code, because exeuting the JavaScript function unfolds more informations that I need to parse.

This is the part where the JavaScript gets called:

```
<a href="javascript:StartUpdate(DIV_TS_4828_5899,41611,5899,';DIV_TS_0_4820;DIV_TS_4820_4828;DIV_TS_4828_5899',0)">
    <img src="bilder/check_on.png" width="15" height="15">
</a>
```

Is it possible to execute this JavaScript function via lxml?
It would be the most comfortable for me, because I would also like to parse the website with lxml afterwards.

I know Selenium could do this, but is there a possibility with lxml?

Comment: No but what happens when the function is executed?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to execute JavaScript language by using parser of eXtensible Markup Language, even with module for parsing HyperText Markup Language.

You need to use JavaScript interpreter to execute JavaScript code.

If you really don't like Selenium you may try to use [PyV8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/) or [PyExecJs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS).